# What is the cheapest way to add wifi to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi

I am trying to find some sort of wifi adapter for Arduino, it needs to be as small as possible (not a shield) and as cheap as possible.

So far I can only seem to find shields that cost about £10+ but I figured that if you can get a replacement wifi adapter for a laptop for next to nothing that I should be able to get a wifi adapter for Arduino much cheaper than this.

It's possible I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: The most cost effective solution is likely not to use a literal Arduino, but rather to utilize something else source-compatible which either has wifi built in, or can host a cheap USB wifi dongle.  It's not entirely out of the question that such a solution, complete, could cost less than a genuine Arduino UNO - and provide a lot more memory and compute resources to work with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some months have passed since my previous answer and now the ESP8266 based WiFi modules are available.

They get connected to your project serially (3.3V) and are controlled in a modem like way using AT commands.

With a pricing of round about $5 they fit the question better than my previous OpenWrt based answer.

For more information about ESP8266 ask your favorite finding machine or [list news with tag ESP8266 at Hackaday](http://hackaday.com/tag/esp8266/).

---

*(Old answer from the pre-ESP8266-days:)*

I vote for a small router reflashed with OpenWrt like "TP-Link TL-WR703N".

It is like building an own Yùn with an Arduino of your choice...

The WR703N:

It has Ethernet, 150MBit WiFi, USB and if you want to solder, a serial console and 2 GPIO-Pins which can be turned into I2C.

This sure is not a chip- or stamp-sized solution but often cheaper than the alternatives, more powerfull and extendable.

Search the net with your favourite find'o'bot for "arduino wr703n" and you'll find lots of examples...

Comment: I've seen it somewhere where they use the I2C for direct connection. This would be slower than direct ethernet, but it reduces costs and size without another ethernet chip

Comment: The easiest way to connect an Arduino to a WR703N is serial via USB.

Comment: The question was asking for "as small as possible, not a shield" and "less than £10". This isn't it.

Comment: @FedericoFissore ... The WR703N in fact **is** one of the **cheapest** ways to bring WiFi and Arduino together. It is not my fault if someone dreams to use **nonexistent** mucht **cheaper** solutions.

Comment: Ok... *now* we have the ESP8266 based modules to add WiFI to your projects... ak your favourite finding machine or http://hackaday.com/tag/esp8266 ...

Answer (score 1):

The Roving Networks RN-XV WiFly module ([found sold at €30](http://www.watterott.com/de/Roving-Networks-RN-XV-WiFly-Module)) might be a solution. I've never tried it. It supports 802.11b/g.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question was asking for less than £10. This isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/CheapWifiShield/index.html
provides a very inexpensive wifi addon for Arduino

[image: Completed Shield]

The WiFi Shield needs just two parts, 4 bits of wire and some soldering equipment. Parts List:-

Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266 Breakout US$9.95 + shipping
Uno Protoshield US$1.88 + shipping
Total US$11.83 (as of June 2015)
For an even cheaper version ~US7 see https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/CheapWifiShield/ESP2866_01_WiFi_Shield/index.html
Both of these need a US10 USB to TTL cable to program them

After you have installed the [pfodESP8266BufferedClient library](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/pfodParserLibraries/pfodESP8266BufferedClient.zip), open the Arduino IDE and copy this sketch, [ESP8266_WifiShield.ino](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/CheapWifiShield/ESP8266_WifiShield.ino.txt), into the IDE.
That provides this setup webpage.
[image: Config webpage]

Comment: While that link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation, you appear to be the author of the site you've linked multiple times.

Comment: Sure I will add a 'my' to future posts.

Answer (score 0):

[Texas Instruments CC3000](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3000) module 10USD/1000pcs, it does only support connecting to AP, i.e. no AdHoc/AP which is useless for direct using with iPad.