# Connecting Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition to the Internet

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

I recently bought an [Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition](http://www.arduino.org/products/boards/arduino-uno-wifi) from [here](http://www.robotshop.com/en/arduino-uno-wifi-microcontroller.html). Although all the other functionality appears to work (I’m able to upload/run programs, read sensors I plug in, etc.), I am not able to connect the Arduino to the internet. The Arduino has a built in ESP8266 chip which is compatible with the WiFi Link library, however, running ScanNetworks in the Arduino mac IDE (File > Examples > WiFi Link > ScanNetworks) doesn't work, nor does it print any errors. Other example files in that library don't work either. The CheckWiFiLinkFirmwareVersion program in the same library will print the welcome message "WiFi Link firmware check." but nothing after that.

I have tried every other WiFi library I could find in the library manager window (Sketch > Include Library > Manage Libraries), namely

- Arduino Uno WiFi Dev Ed Library
- WiFiEsp
- WiFi101
- WiFi

However, none of them work. Is the Arduino's WiFi chip defective, or am I doing something wrong? One reviews on the website that I bought the Arduino from said this (see [lenny](http://www.robotshop.com/en/arduino-uno-wifi-microcontroller.html#customer-reviews)):

> Arduino.org (which is different from arduino.cc) has not made software available to access the WiFi capabilities of this board. As far as I can tell, the wifi cannot be used. They keep saying that the software is coming soon.
>
> See this thread on their forum: http://www.arduino.org/forums/uno/arduino-uno-wifi-arduinowifi-library-incomplete-solution-for-mqtt-tcp-udp-socket-communication-540

In summary, is the Arduino Uno WiFi Developer Edition known to be defective? If not, what am I doing wrong? If it is, could I potentially get a WiFi shield and use that instead of the built in chip? I have other shields for the Arduino (e.g. an SD card shield) that are working fine.

Comment: Re your quote : Arduino and Genuino "merged" (maybe not technically, but in essence) a few days ago when the Chairman came back and the row ended and all became lovely in the world again.  So this may well change in the near future.  It may be worth posting a question to push the issue on the Arduino forum.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the Webgui?

with the Webgui you can configure the wifi settings.
you do not need to upload sketches for this.
It is a good test if there is no defect.

Connect your PC Wi-Fi or with your smartphone directly to the Aduino uno wifi.
Start your browser and type in the following IP: 192.168.240.1
and now you should see the WebGUI.

Answer (score 0):

The correct WiFi library for that board is here:

- https://github.com/arduino-libraries/UnoWiFi-Developer-Edition-Lib

If that is not working you may have a defective board. Maybe the ESP8266 firmware is incorrect.

Comment: That GitHub link is just the repo to the "Arduino Uno WiFi Dev Ed Library", which I already installed through the library manager window in the mac desktop IDE. The [ReadMacAddress](https://goo.gl/siATsF) example program in that library prints "Please, push the  ESP B/L button on the board and plug the USB cable before run the sketch," but after doing both things, it doesn't work. Interestingly, I see "Arduino-Uno-WiFi-823889" in the list of WiFi networks on my computer. Is that a sign that it does work and I am just doing something wrong? I bought two Arduinos, and neither can connect.

Comment: If the built in WiFi chip does not work because the Arduino Uno WiFi is new and still in development, can you recommend a good WiFi shield that has been around a while, is supported by the community, and works with the Uno and its variants?

Comment: The Arduino WiFi Shield maybe?

Comment: This [popular question on Arduino.SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/436/37046) gives all the ways to connect an Arduino to WiFi. It mentions both the [Arduino WiFi Shield](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-wifi-shield) and the cheaper ESP8266 chip. However, if you click through the link, it says the WiFi shield is retired. Why is that? Am I better off with an [ethernet shield](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-ethernet-shield-2)?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is not defective. You just don't understand how it works, because of it's architecture. In addition the original firmware and the UnoWifiDefEd library are strange and limited. I recommend using WiFi Link firmware and library. 
I currently write a community documentation for the [Uno WiFi & WiFi Link](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-firmware-wifilink/blob/ota/UNOWIFI_DEV_ED.md)